# How to Import an External .class File in an Eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, class, import

I am trying to include a .class file through an import in a .java class I am creating. I need the .java class to look the same as what I need to deploy on the application server. I have created a directory structure to put the Context.class file in.

[image]

I updated the build path by using "Add External Class Folder..." and selected the "oracle" directory containing apps>fnd>common.

[image]

However, Eclipse still can't find the Context.class file referenced in the import.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `classes` (`C:\Users\badams\java\classes`) directory instead of the `oracle` directory when using `Add External Class Folder...`.

You should provide the root of the directory that represent your java package structure.

As an alternative, you can create a jar archive with the contents of the `C:\Users\badams\java\classes` directory and add that archive as a jar dependency as well.

You can use for this purpose the builtin SDK `jar` utility. Please, change you current directory to `C:\Users\badams\java\classes` and run from a command prompt or PowerShell terminal something like:

```sh
jar cvf oracle-fnd.jar *
```

Then add the generated archive to your project as usual.